# Search Form Help

Tags: search, forms

Is there an option I can put in the advanced_form search form to get the results to load into the top window? I'm using the advanced form in an iframe, and I need the results to load into the "_top" layer.

As an alternative, I've taken the rendered search form and adjusted it to work, so if there's no option in the standard code, I'm ok. I can get everything working except one thing. I can't get this value to autogenerate:

`<input type="hidden" name="meta" value="Y1q3nU/3/C6nkc+TMjbxHkfdkE77...." />`

Is there a variable I can use here?

EE2.10.1

Comment: Would you consider a jQuery solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590536/jquery-to-change-form-target-value

Comment: That gave me an idea!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks AllInOne! That sparked a solution. You can do this with some jQuery to add missing the target attribute. After the search form code, put:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#searchform').attr('target', '_top');
</script>
```